# Automapper mapping generic property from ISource => IDest, then specifying remaining mappings

Tags: c#, interface, .net-core, polymorphism, automapper

My situation is I must merge the name of a related object to a `name` property on many different models. Those models have implementations which need their own configurations.

What I've tried is:

ProjectFrom.cs

```
public interface IProjectFrom {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectFromConcreteA : IProjectFrom {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

ProjectTo.cs

```
public interface IProjectTo {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectToConcreteA : IProjectTo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

Profile.cs

```
CreateMap<IProjectFrom, IProjectTo>()
            .ForMember(projection => projection.Name, expression => expression.ResolveUsing<ProjectionResolver>());
CreateMap<ProjectFromConcreteA, ProjectToConcreteA>()
    .ForMember(concreteTo => concreteTo.SomeProp, expression => expression.MapFrom(concreteFrom => concreteFrom.SomeProp));
```

ProjectionResolver.cs

```
public class ProjectionResolver : IValueResolver<IProjectFrom, IProjectTo, string>
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;
    public ProjectionResolver(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
    public string Resolve(IProjectFrom source, IProjectTo destination,
        string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _dependency.GetStringFor(source.Id);
    }
}
```

However this does not seem to work as my Resolver is never used. Am I missing a step?

Comment: You need to include the mapping profile for your interfaces on your concrete types. http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker I see what you're referring to; do you additionally know if there is an automatic way of doing this? It seems to me like concrete mapping should not need to rely on an explicit config in this case

Comment: There's an inefficient, [lazy man's way](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/d8e77bddabc6038846a05a51264fef9e9e46951b/src/AutoMapper/IMappingExpressionBase.cs#L105).

Comment: Would you prefer to post an answer that can be accepted?